# Usb 2.0 and esata combo max speed

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3, esata, usb-2

What is the speed of usb 2.0 and esata combo. I am getting almost same speed on combo as well as seprate usb 2.0 port with External HDD as well pendrive 3.0.
I am getting speed aorund 105 MBPS in begning. Sometimes it sustain around 60 MBPS while most of the time goes down to 30 MBPS.

System Configuration
Lenovo Ideapad Z570 (2012 model)
8GB RAM
Core i5 2.4 GHz
HDD 750GB

Comment: Your speeds are what I would expect for a USB 2.0 device.

Comment: So you mean the speed is fine even for esata combo?

Comment: The speed will be the same as the slowest link you are going through. If you are passing through USB 2 to an esata adaptor then the USB 2 is going to determine the maximum speed you get. USB 2 has a theoretical limit of 480 Mbps (mega bits) which after protocol overheads and other devices take their cut ends up around 30-ish mega-bytes per second.

Comment: @ram619 The speeds you are measure are what I would expect out of any USB 2.0 device.  If you want faster speeds take the USB 2.0 out of the picture.